# Can't run Vulkan on Ubuntu 18.04 with NVidia

Tags: nvidia, graphics, vulkan

When running `vulkaninfo`, I get the following error.

It's been weeks that I try to get it running correctly on Ubuntu (vs 15 minutes flawlessly on Mac), trying almost every solution I stumbled upon. Any help would be very much appreciated.

> Vulkan Instance Version: 1.1.85
>   vulkan/1.1.85.0/examples/vulkaninfo.c:3357: failed with VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED

**Steps followed:**

Here are the steps I followed in order to get there.

1. I checked recommended NVidia driver

   ```
   sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
   ```
2. I installed NVidia-driver-390 as recommended

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-390
   ```
3. I rebooted and realized that `nvidia-prime` is not being used

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime
   ```

   Still no nvidia Prime tab in Nvidia X Server Settings, let's try without.
4. Download the vulkan SDK and [followed these steps](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/sdk/latest/linux/getting_started.html)
5. Add to `~/.profile`.

   ```
   export VULKAN_SDK=/home/mies/vulkan/1.1.85.0/x86_64
   export PATH=$VULKAN_SDK/bin:$PATH
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$VULKAN_SDK/lib
   export VK_LAYER_PATH=$VULKAN_SDK/etc/explicit_layer.d
   ```
6. Build the examples. None works, I get this error.

   ```
   vulkan/1.1.85.0/examples/cube.c:3155: demo_init_vk: Assertion `!err' failed.
   [1]    31349 abort (core dumped)  ./cube
   ```
7. When running `vulkaninfo` I get the error

   ```
   VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED.
   ```

**Am I missing something?**
**Context is:**

Driver check:

```
lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF106GL [Quadro 2000] (rev a1)  
Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Quadro 2000D  
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

**Config:**

`/usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json`:

```
{
    "file_format_version" : "1.0.0",
    "ICD": {
        "library_path": "libGLX_nvidia.so.0",
        "api_version" : "1.0.65"
    }
}
```

Run `via`

```
dpkg-query: no packages found matching lunarg-vulkan-sdk  
VIA_ERROR:   Vulkan failed to find a compatible driver.
```

Run `dpkg-query -l "nvidia*"` (w/ quotes for zsh)

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold  
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend  
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                        Version                    Architecture               Description

un  nvidia-304                                  <none>                     <none>                     (no description available)
un  nvidia-340                                  <none>                     <none>                     (no description available)
un  nvidia-384                                  <none>                     <none>                     (no description available)
un  nvidia-390                                  <none>                     <none>                     (no description available)
un  nvidia-common                               <none>                     <none>                     (no description available)
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-390                    390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1    amd64                      NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-dkms-390                             390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1    amd64                      NVIDIA DKMS package
un  nvidia-dkms-kernel                          <none>                     <none>                     (no description available)
ii  nvidia-driver-390                           390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1    amd64                      NVIDIA driver metapackage
un  nvidia-driver-binary                        <none>                     <none>                     (no description available)
un  nvidia-kernel-common                        <none>                     <none>                     (no description available)
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-390                    390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1    amd64                      Shared files used with the kernel module
un  nvidia-kernel-source                        <none>                     <none>                     (no description available)
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-390                    390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1    amd64                      NVIDIA kernel source package
un  nvidia-legacy-340xx-vdpau-driver            <none>                     <none>                     (no description available)
un  nvidia-opencl-icd                           <none>                     <none>                     (no description available)
un  nvidia-persistenced                         <none>                     <none>                     (no description available)
ii  nvidia-prime                                0.8.8.1                    all                        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                             390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1    amd64                      Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
un  nvidia-settings-binary                      <none>                     <none>                     (no description available)
un  nvidia-smi                                  <none>                     <none>                     (no description available)
un  nvidia-utils                                <none>                     <none>                     (no description available)
ii  nvidia-utils-390                            390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1    amd64                      NVIDIA driver support binaries
un  nvidia-vdpau-driver                         <none>                     <none>                     (no description available)
```

I'm running out of ideas.
My NVidia Quadro 2000D is supposed to be supported, right?